# Angular 2 url parameters

Tags: angular

How I can add trailing slash to the end of url for specific component?
(My client requires it, so no need to add a comment saying; don't use trailing slash).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need a custom https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/DefaultUrlSerializer-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by defining your routes with a trailing slash and then making sure to navigate to the url with the slash. It will most likely result in a few headaches because the router will be one level deeper than you would expect because of the trailing slash.

Routes

```json
{
    path: 'a/',
    component: AComponent
},
{
    path: 'list/b/',
    component: BComponent,
}
```

You can get the router to add the trailing slash by adding an empty string path after the defined route. If you write the slash yourself, like `[routerLink]="['/a/']"` angular will remove it.

Link

```html
<p><a [routerLink]="['/a', '']">Component A</a></p>
```

or

```html
<p><a [routerLink]="['../a', '']">Component A</a></p>
```

Programatically Navigate

```js
this.router.navigate(['/a', '']);
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/77kAwx3mLiQJVjOQMFS2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement a custom `UrlSerializer`. It could look something like this:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer  {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url);
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
        let url = super.serialize(tree);
        url = url.length > 1 ? url += '/' : url;

        return url;
    }
}
```

Then provide it in your `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...
                {provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer}
              ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Perfect, minimally intrusive solution. This resolves the problem with Azure hosted Angular routes which contain a dot character in their route parameters that break when a refresh is requested. Azure gets confused by a url which contains a dot followed by some alphanumeric characters, unless there is a trailing slash at the end of the path.

Comment: I would slightly improve the code by changing the line to `url = url.length > 1 && !url.endsWith('/') ? url += '/' : url;`